# Need to pass json array in Json Object using map key value pair in volley request

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have the following code, in which the Json has has array of objects. I am using Map to pass my parameters in android volley PUT request. Is there any way I may add Json array of object in my Json to be sent. 
My code

```
 try {
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.PUT, requestURL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            if (!response.equals(null)) {
                Log.e("Your Array Response", response);
            } else {
                Log.e("Your Array Response", "Data Null");
            }
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("error is ", "" + error);
        }
    }) {

        //This is for Headers If You Needed
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            params.put("token", "ACCESS_TOKEN");
            return params;
        }

        //Pass Your Parameters here
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("User", UserName);
            params.put("Pass", PassWord);
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    queue.add(request);

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My Json format is as mentioned below:

```
{
  "name": "string",
  "desc": "string",

  "tags": [
    {
      "name": "string"
    }
  ],
  "ingredients": [
    {
      "name": "string"
    }
  ],
  "available": true,
  "availabilities": [
    {
      "start_time": "string",
      "end_time": "string",
      "day_of_the_week": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: is this a response json file ? You need to prase this data

Comment: Yes. This Json I need to pass in PUT request